# How to cast a StreamSubscription to Stream?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a widget that needs a stream so it can listen to the events and when the widget is disposed, I also dispose of the stream. This is done by:

```dart
class MyWidget {
  StreamSubscription? subscription;
  MyWidget(Stream stream) {
    subscription = stream.listen(null);
    subscription.onData(/* CODE */)
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    subscription?.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

The problem is that I only have a StreamSubscription to pass to `MyWidget` and I can't just use this StreamSubscription because it would also cancel the stream that is being used by other widgets.

Not canceling the stream inside `MyWidget` is also not an option because it generates errors since the widget was already disposed.

Unless I'm missing something here, the only option is to cast the original StreamSubscription to a Stream.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a StreamSubscription, you can use the asBroadcastStream() method to get a Stream that you can pass to your widget. This way, the original stream will not be canceled when the widget is disposed.